# CraftCMS vs WordPress vs other CMSs

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system

We're considering a new CMS for our huge 10-20,000 page site. We are not currently using any CMS, but have individual html pages with the content embedded(!).

Our site is mostly 'regular' content types, with a few discussion boards and some document handling. We also have a number of news sections/blogs and some profile directories.

We have few developers with limited coding skills and even fewer coders on the team. We've considered WordPress (which we're already using for a few sites) and also CraftCMS. CraftCMS seems more fitting to our needs because it's flexible and lean; we're impressed with what we've seen so far but are concerned that it's not open-source and that it's so new. WordPress seems cumbersome to the coding developers as much of the system is 'out of the box' and requires loading lots of plugins and things that you don't 'need' for a page.

Are there other similar CMSs that people can recommend for us to consider? Please don't tell me about your favorite CMS; please DO tell me about a CMS that you know of that may fit our needs. Comments on the CMSs mentioned above in the context of our needs are welcomed as well.

Thank you.

Comment: Wordpress is an abysmal platform. It is full of legacy junk that they can't get rid of without breaking everything, and full security holes. Go with anything... *anything*... but not WordPress. CraftCMS is good. I would also recommend Joomla (lots of plugins and community) and OctoberCMS (easy to use, modern and well written).

Comment: why the downvotes?

Comment: It seems a bit odd to be asking why now, two and a half years later, but it's mainly because questions like this asking 'which product to use' are considered off-topic for SO and are ususally closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CraftCMS is as impressive as it looks, I've built 4 sites so far with it and the more I use it the more I discover thoughtful little details that make development easier. This is particularly true for content rich sites with lots of variables & different article types.

Compared to Wordpress and other similar systems I have used, you will be amazed at how few plugins are required even for complex layouts & implementations.

The newness concern is totally valid too. I waited for almost 3 years before doing any client work for that very reason. Wanted to see if a stable dev community would develop around it and to be sure that it would be financially viable for the developers. The creator recent addressed this issue and open source concerns on Hacker News here:

https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12009552

Answer (score 0):

***ExpressionEngine 2*** was always the choice for bigger, more robust sites. But when *CraftCMS* burst into the scene we felt it addressed some of ExpressionEngine's shortcomings. We we waited until `Craft 2.0` to switch. Here a few reasons why:

- **TWIG templates:** believe me, you want your templates to be as modular, and as clean, as possible. Twig is incredible powerful and it has great documentation.
- **Matrix Field:** If you not used to, it takes a while to wrap your head around the concept of "Content Blocks". But once you do, tackling complex content is a breeze.
- **Great community:** I know Wordpress has a giant community, but that is actually bad IMO. Of course you want the community to be big, but once it gets to size, it can be hard to know who to ask for help. Craft community is in that sweet spot where you can find (good) help pretty fast. I also find that projects that have a person/company behind the product are great on raining in community issues.
- ***First Party E-Commerce support:*** about a third of the projects we work on it has some kind of commerce in it. Not having to rely on third-party plugins is refreshing.

We've also checked other offerings, such as Statamic, ExpressionEngine 3, and even some Node based CMS's. But Craft really does mostly a better job then the others.

I hope it helps!

Comment: Curious to hear what Node-based CMS's you've tried, because I haven't found one yet that was worth the effort of installing it.

Comment: We've looking into [KeystoneJS](http://keystonejs.com) and [ApostropheCMS](http://apostrophecms.org). We liked the later because it uses [Nunjucks](https://mozilla.github.io/nunjucks), which is very similar to Twig.

Comment: Okay thanks. I really didn't like Keystone much, but I never saw Apostrophe so I'll follow up on that.